# node-redis with bluebird promises refactoring

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following nodejs code in its most basic stage:

```
var bluebird = require("bluebird"),
    redis = require('redis');

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);
function printOutput(data) {
    console.log('Output:' + data);
}
function printRedisPop(data) {
   if (data !== null) {
       console.log('Still going...');
       return 1;
   } else {
      console.log('Nothing left');
      return 0;
   }
}
// redis is the usual node_redis object. Do what you usually do with it:
var client = redis.createClient(6379,'127.0.0.1');
client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("uh oh", err);
});

for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
// All your redis commands return promises now.
    client.lpushAsync('x', i)
        .then(printOutput)
        .catch(console.log);
}
var x = function() {
    return bluebird.resolve().reflect().then(function(){
        return 'done';
    });
}

for (var i=0;i<100;i++) {
// All your redis commands return promises now.
    client.rpopAsync('x')
        .then(printRedisPop)
        .catch(console.log);
}

bluebird.resolve().reflect().then(function(){
    console.log('done');
});

client.quit();
```

What I am trying to do is an easy FIFO queue using redis Lpush and Rpop. In php it works well but I am trying to put it in play with Node. Every console.log section will eventually an operation when the promise comes back. My problem is that I am very fresh with the concept of promise design. I do know that it is an efficient way to do callbacks, async, and to troubleshoot issues due to the then/catch.

in theory here in `printRedisPop` if data is null (ie there is nothing left to rpop) I can client.quit() and process.exit();

(hence why the second for loop is at 100 as I know for a fact that it will have exceeded the 10 items that I am putting in.)

What I want to do is run an infinite loop to "rpop" items from redis and process them and to continue so until the list is empty. Once empty I have other things to do - hence why I didn't want to continously chain them nested within `then()` functions or kill the application with a process.exit. I am tempted to throw an error and catch it to exit but I heard that is bad practice also. One thing I tried to do is to "wait" at the resolve/reflect and check the then() function value however what I get:

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

Comment: Why do you have so many `bluebird.resolve().reflect()` with a `then()` that ignores the value?

Comment: @Ryan Looks like a poor man's `finally`

Comment: You cannot do a "loop", unless you use `async`/`await` syntax. Use recursion instead.

Comment: @Ryan - I'm running some code translating from PHP that works that I have built into a NodeJs project.

Comment: Promises won’t pause your function. They’re not magic. (For that, look to `async`/`await`.) If you want to wait for one to complete and read its value, that needs to happen in a `.then()`/`.catch()`/etc. transformation. I suggest you start with a simpler exercise.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not doing this for practice. I have an application in nodejs that I am trying to sub redis as a storage. Php solution is easy for me but I needed to translated this to nodejs because of the existing code - if you have a solution in proper utilizing the promises or using your alternative solutions please submit something that I can use - tks,

Comment: @azngunit81: Doesn’t matter if you’re doing it for practice; you need to learn how promises work to use them, so practice with something easier first and start reading read up.